# Expressionengine mysql help needed! - get entry from category A & (B OR C)

Tags: mysql, expressionengine, categories

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days and I'm getting nothing back from the EE forums. Essentially I'm trying to do this (see the category bit):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" category="7&(175|177)"}
```

but you can't mix AND/OR category requests with native tags out of the box

I've been trying to write a custom query to handle it but I'm stuck on how to handle the category posts table.

Currently my query looks like this but the category query doesn't work.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT 
             type.cat_id, 
             type.cat_name as cat_name, 
             type.cat_url_title,
             type.group_id,
             t.title as title,
             t.status,
             t.channel_id,
             t.site_id,
             d.field_id_32 as date,
             p.cat_id as cat_id
            FROM 
             exp_categories type JOIN 
             exp_category_posts p ON type.cat_id = p.cat_id JOIN
             exp_channel_titles t ON p.entry_id = t.entry_id JOIN
             exp_channel_data d ON t.entry_id = d.entry_id
            WHERE 
             t.status = 'open' AND
             t.site_id = 1 AND
             type.group_id = 2 AND
             /* problem bit! */
             (p.cat_id = 7 AND ((p.cat_id = 175) OR (p.cat_id = 177))) AND
             t.channel_id = 3
            GROUP BY 
             type.cat_id
            ORDER BY
             type.cat_order
  LIMIT 5"}
```

If anyone has done something like this before or can see where I'm going wrong I'm really appreciate a steer!

Comment: Is there a single column of category??/
The problem is due to 
"(p.cat_id = 7 AND ((p.cat_id = 175) OR (p.cat_id = 177)))"

Both the condition is checked to a single row, for which the success is not possible as p.cat_id will have a single value..

Comment: That's what I was worried about, you're absolutely right Sashi. I can't get my head around how to pull in all of the category posts that match the x AND y OR z and then match those results up to the entries. Do you think I can do it with a sql query, or would I be better off falling back to PHP and trying to do it that way, with an array or something?

Comment: You can achieve that ...Check my sample query..

Comment: Hey Sashi, where's the sample query? Am I being blind as well as stupid? :)

Comment: please give me some time, will write your query in a while.
tell me 1 thing, Will the value of category different for any specific channel. Or what I mean is that is it possible to have a channel="event" and category 7,71,2,7

Comment: The first category_id is constant (ie they all need to come from 7) but then it could be 175 OR 177 - but it has to match one or the other. Scott's solution using EE tags, plus a smattering of php could work though - a query would just be a lot more efficient!

Answer (score 1):

Wow, what a query!  How about taking a little step back?  Why not make your outer loop just part of the logic, then do the balance inside the loop:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" category="7"}
  {categories show="175|177"}
    {!-- do stuff --}
  {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

That might be just what you need for a nice Friday ;)

-s.

Comment: A simple and clever approach - but the downside is that all of the *limit* parameter, and the `{count}` and `{total_results}` variables will be rendered useless.

Comment: You're right Derek, it does - I'm thinking of possibly outputting the results into a php array and then manipulating them that way. This approach is more expensive than a straight query, but it's the closest I've come to the results I need - so thanks Scott!

Comment: @DerekHogue:  it might be a moot point, but I agree about this technique breaking `{count}` and `{total_results}`, but also think that the limit= parameter would still work fine if placed in the `{categories}` tag

Answer (score 1):

This can't be accomplished in a single query. I'd build a simple plugin for this (get started with [pkg.io](http://pkg.io)) and do a couple of queries, returning entry_ids to be passed to a Channel Entries tag.

```
$cat_7_entries = $final_entries = array();
$cat_7_query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT entry_id FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id = 7");
if($cat_7_query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach($cat_7_query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $cat_7_entries[] = $row['entry_id'];
    }
    $cat_7_entries = implode(',', $cat_7_entries);

    $entries_query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT entry_id FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id IN(175,177) AND entry_id IN(".$cat_7_entries.")");
    if($entries_query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($entries_query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $final_entries[] = $row['entry_id'];
        }
        $vars = array(0 => array('entry_ids' => implode('|', $final_entries)));
        return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
    }
}
```

Then just wrap a standard Channel Entries tag with your plugin tag, using parse="inward".

```
{exp:my_plugin:my_method parse="inward"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" entry_id="{entry_ids}"}
...
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:my_plugin:my_method}
```

The beauty with this is that the standard Channel Entries tag does all the checking of channel, status, expiration date, etc, etc for you, but will only return entries that match all that AND your specified list of qualifying entry_ids.

Comment: WOW! I've never seen pkg.io before - thanks for the heads up! Also thanks for this code, I'm going to give it a try and possibly add some parameters to handle the various ids etc. Thanks Derek!

Answer (score 1):

@Penzizzle I think the secret here is that you need to basically examine the three categories you are interested in *each in their own column*.

Here is a simplified version of your query that demonstrates this technique:

```
SELECT 
   t.entry_id,
   cat1.cat_id as cat1,
   cat2.cat_id as cat2,
   cat3.cat_id as cat3
FROM
   exp_weblog_titles t
JOIN
   exp_category_posts as cat1 ON cat1.entry_id = t.entry_id
JOIN
   exp_category_posts as cat2 ON cat2.entry_id = t.entry_id
JOIN
   exp_category_posts as cat3 ON cat3.entry_id = t.entry_id
WHERE
   cat1.cat_id = 175 AND (cat2.cat_id = 177 OR cat3.cat_id = 175)
```

See what that does for you?

Answer (score 0):

try this where clause:

```
WHERE 
  t.status = 'open' AND
  t.site_id = 1 AND
  type.group_id = 2 AND
  t.channel_id = 3 AND
  p.cat_id = 7 OR p.cat_id = 175 OR p.cat_id = 177
```

if you really want this logic:

```
/* problem bit! */
(p.cat_id = 7 AND ((p.cat_id = 175) OR (p.cat_id = 177))) AND
```

then you might have to reorganize your table and logic.

Comment: Thanks Duffy, that way would work but I really need the entry to come from category 7 AND match either 175 or 177. I'm starting to wonder if this is doable with just a query as each category post has a single entry - for example if I post an entry and give it three categories, then there will be three category_post rows for that single entry - which is why my dumb logic doesn't work!

Comment: you have to think about, that the where clause works here for each row. and the cat_id of this row can't be 7 AND (175 OR 177) 
i can only be 7 or 175 or 177.